# How can I move the google-chrome folder from ~/.config to a new location?

Tags: google-chrome

google-chrome (not chromium) seems to be the main offender in periodically filling up my undersized boot drive.  I'd like to move that directory (not my entire user directory) to a new location.

Is there a 'right' way to do this? How would I go about it?

e.g., from /home/me/.config/google-chrome
to /media/biggerdrive/google-chrome

I considered playing with the various types of links but don't really know enough to be comfortable or to know if that's a workable option.

Comment: Are you certain it is the `google-chrome` directory in `~/.config` and not `~/.cache` that is eating up your hard drive space?

Comment: I think, the "right way" is using a symbolic link (see `man ln`) which redirects the directory to the bigger drive.

Comment: I agree with @xiota. On my system .config is 108MB and .cache is 838MB.

Comment: I ran the disk usage utility and it was because of files created under .config.  I agree, they would be better placed in cache (especially since I deleted some of the files with no apparent ill effect ... several with sizes up to 5 gigabytes).

Comment: When I said, 'right way' I meant configurable from within chrome.  Not that any other way wouldn't be functionally as good.

Comment: Now that I know what you meant by 'right way', I found a command-line option that will do that you want `google-chrome --disk-cache-dir="/tmp/chromium"`.  As far as I can tell, there is no way to set this permanently from within the gui, so symbolic link might still be the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options for relocating folders.  Which is most appropriate to use depends on circumstances.

### application-specific configuration

Changing configuration settings from within an application is usually preferred if such a setting exists.  However, many programs are hard coded to use specific folders.

For Google Chrome, there is a command line setting that can be used:

```
google-chrome --disk-cache-dir="/tmp/chromium"
```

This change can be made semi-permanent by changing `*.desktop` files, but 
doing so is cumbersome and likely to break.  So a more generic method may be preferred.

### symbolic links

This is the approach you mention in your question.  It is the easiest, and the method I would try first in the situation you describe.  Copy or create the new folder at the desired location and use the `ln -s` command:

```
ln -s [new-location] [old-location]
```

This is the only type of link that will work with folders.  Hard links (created with `ln` without the `-s` option) work only with files.

Beware, links can be broken if either the target folder or the link itself are moved.

### bind mount

A bind mount can be thought of as mounting a folder instead of a partition.  I would use this approach if I wanted several mount points to share a partition, but did not want to use symbolic links.  For instance, if a program misbehaves when encountering symbolic links.

- [What is a bind mount?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198590)

### dedicated partition (or drive)

Usually, to prevent the `/` partition from filling up, a separate `/home` partition is used.  Also common is to put `/var` into its own partition.  You can read more here:

- [What mount points exist on a typical Linux system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12040)

This approach is best taken during a fresh installation of the operating system.  Changing the partition structure of an already running system is cumbersome.